# Calculating Sales Tax in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble calculating tax and then adding it to the subtotal. Just so you are aware I am very new to coding in general. the goal is to have the tirePrice,tireAmount, and tireFees all added up and taxed and then the coupons should be taken off. also if you have any tips to improve let me know but as I said keep in mind I am very new to this.
Thank you for your time :).

```js
function computePrice() {
    var tirePrice = document.getElementById('tirePrice').value;
    var tireAmount = document.getElementById('tireAmount').value;
    var tireFees = document.getElementById('tireFees').value;
    var tireCoupons = document.getElementById('tireCoupons').value;
    var finalPrice = ((+tirePrice * +tireAmount + +tireFees) * .8 - +tireCoupons).toFixed(2);
    finalPrice = finalPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById('finalPrice').innerHTML = "Total:$" + finalPrice;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>BJ's Tire Bay Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h1>BJ's Tire Bay Calculator </h1>
    <p>Price Per Tire: $ <input id="tirePrice" type="number" min="1" max="100000"></p>
    <p>Number Of Tires: <input id="tireAmount" type="number" min="1" max="4"></p>
    <p>Installation Fee and NYS Recycling Fee: $<input id="tireFees" type="number" min="1" max="70"></p>
    <p>Coupons: $ <input id="tireCoupons" type="number" max="100000"></p>
    <input id="displayNum" value="Calculate" type="button" onclick="computePrice()">
    <h2 id="finalPrice"></h2>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? The code to calculate the tax doesn't seem to be in there at all.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by `.8`? Is that supposed to be the tax?

Comment: Tax is *added* to the total. If you have 8% tax, you need to multiply by `1.08`.

Comment: Your confusion seems to be with arithmetic, not programming.

Comment: Why (+x * +y + +z - +b) and not just (x*y + z - b) ?
You can also use innerText and not innerHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out how you're going to calculate sales tax first. You can look into other resources but [this one](https://www.avalara.com/taxrates/en/calculator.html) seems to give a good example. There's also inclusive and exclusive sales tax. I'm not getting into that --

Once you have that math, you can then do something similar:

```js
const calculateSalesTax = (amount, taxPercent) => {
  // Whatever math is involved to calculate your sales tax here
  return amount + (taxPercent * amount);
};

document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = () => {
  const amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  const tax = document.getElementById('percent').value;
  document.getElementById('total').innerText = `$ ${calculateSalesTax(+amount, +tax)}`;
};
```

```html
<label for="amount">Amount</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="amount" id="amount" />

<label for="percent">Sales Tax</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="percent" id="percent" />

<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<div id="total"></div>
```